# Conditional results from SQL Server CASE statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

Is it possible to do a boolean compare in the when-expression on a case-expression within a SQL Server case statement. I have a SELECT statement that has logic similar to the following:

```
SELECT T1.ProductNumber,
    CASE
        WHEN (SELECT SUM(T2.Quantity) FROM Table2 AS T2 WHERE T2.Product=T1.Product) IS NULL
            THEN T1.Quantity
        WHEN (SELECT SUM(T2.Quantity) FROM Table2 AS T2 WHERE T2.Product=T1.Product) > T1.Quantity
            THEN T1.Quantity
        ELSE T1.Quantity - (SELECT SUM(T2.Quantity) FROM Table2 AS T2 WHERE T2.Product=T1.Product)
    END
FROM Table1 AS T1
```

This seems like a lot of duplicated lookups on Table2. If possible I'd like to do something like this:

```
SELECT T1.ProductNumber,
    CASE (SELECT SUM(T2.Quantity) FROM Table2 AS T2 WHERE T2.Product=T1.Product) as altQty
        WHEN altQty IS NULL
            THEN T1.Quantity
        WHEN altQty > T1.Quantity
            THEN T1.Quantity
        ELSE T1.Quantity - altQty
    END
FROM Table1 AS T1
```

Comment: Don't forget that [`CASE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) always needs an `END`.

Comment: Good spot Tim. Just knocked it together as an example, original was way too unwieldy, but always worth pointing out. Edited original question to include ENDs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't reference the alias that way, but you can if you put it in a subquery / derived table.

```
SELECT ProductNumber, CASE WHEN altQty IS NULL
            THEN Quantity
        WHEN altQty > Quantity
            THEN Quantity
        ELSE Quantity - altQty END
FROM 
(
  SELECT T1.ProductNumber, T1.Quantity, 
    altQty = (SELECT SUM(T2.Quantity) FROM Table2 AS T2 WHERE T2.Product=T1.Product)
  FROM Table1 AS T1
) AS x;
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response. Was trying to see if I could do it without the subquery, but good to know that it's just no possible. New to this so accepting the top answer even though they are all valid, hope that's right.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT T1.ProductNumber,
    CASE 
        WHEN T2.Qty IS NULL
            THEN T1.Quantity
        WHEN T2.Qty > T1.Quantity
            THEN T1.Quantity
        ELSE T1.Quantity - T2.Qty END
FROM Table1 AS T1
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT ProductNumber, SUM(Quantity) AS Qty FROM Table2 GROUP BY ProductNumber) AS T2
        ON T1.ProductNumber = T2.ProductNumber
```

Answer (score 1):

No, but you can remove the duplicate lookups.

```
SELECT ProductNumber,
       CASE WHEN T2Quantity IS NULL THEN T1Quantity
            WHEN T2Quantity > T1Quantity THEN T1Quantity
            ELSE T1Quantity - T2Quantity END
  FROM
   (SELECT T1.ProductNumber, T1.Quantity as T1Quantity, SUM(T2.Quantity) as T2Quantity
      FROM Table1 AS T1 LEFT OUTER JOIN 
           Table2 AS T2 ON T2.Product=T1.Product
     GROUP BY T1.ProductNumber) innerTbl
```